# Android DownloadManager - file stuck at queued

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-download-manager, android-11

I've been duck-ducking all day and I couldn't find any solution. Everything pointed to broken system (I should update google services etc.). I didn't set up any intent handlers as I just want to start the download and forget (there are handlers for finished download and notification click).

I'm trying to download files at my React Native app. My native android code looks like this:

```java
public void download(String name, String fileName, String description, String mimeType, String url) {
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

        request.setTitle(name);
        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        request.setDescription(description);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
        request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

It works on my Mi 9 SE with android 9, but It doesn't work on android 11 emulator. The download will get stuck at queued like this (It will change to unsuccessful after few minutes):

[image]

EDIT:
I'm calling this function with valid params:

```
    NativeModules.DownloadUtilsModule.download(
      "Your recording",
      "recording.mp4",
      "Your recording",
      "video/mp4",
      valid_url,
    );
```

Comment: Try some other destinations. Also try to use setDestinationUri().

Answer (score 0):

for downloading a file(music, video, audio, pdf) in react-native you can use `rn-fetch-blob` and `react-native-fs`. Here is a simple code with may help you.

```
export  const downloadfile = async (downloadpath, selectedfile) => {
            // api level 29 and above
            let  options = {
                fileCache: false,
                addAndroidDownloads : {
                    useDownloadManager :true,
                    notification : true,
                    mime : "application/pdf",
                    title:`DownLoading Your File`,
                    description : 'Downloading File',
                    path: `${DIR29ORABOVE}${selectedfile.split(".")[0]}.pdf` 
                }
            }
        
            try{
                RNFetchBlob.config(options).fetch('GET', downloadpath)
                .then((res) => {
                   
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err, "DownLoading Error")
                })
        
            }catch(err){
                
            }
            
        
    }
```